# Conditional calculation in R

Tags: r, intervals

I have been having some issues with calculating time between events based on conditions. I would like to determine, the time between when a refund was made to a customer and their previous purchase. That is, time of refund minus the time of their last purchase by ID. There are multiple users grouped by ID, each with multiple events (purchases or refunds) indexed by a TIMESTAMP. The relevant rows of the table look like this:

```
View(df1)
TIMESTAMP   ID  Order_Type
2017-05-04  55  Purchase
2017-05-12  55  Purchase
2017-05-18  55  Purchase
2017-06-16  55  Refund 
2017-05-06  36  Purchase
2017-05-14  36  Purchase
2017-05-22  36  Purchase
2017-06-14  36  Purchase
2017-06-28  36  Refund 
2017-07-10  36  Purchase
```

As in the table, there are cases where a client was issued a refund, but then later made a purchase. I would only want the calculation to be from the previous purchase date until refund. I'm thinking I could use something along the lines of the aggregate function.

With the output as:

```
View(df2)
TIMESTAMP   ID  Days_Since_Last_Purchase
2017-06-16  55     29
2017-06-28  36     14
```

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example? You can `dput(df1)` and provide the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution in base R that works:

```
df$TIMESTAMP <- as.Date.character(df$TIMESTAMP, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

inds <- which(df$Order_Type == "Refund")
df2  <- df[inds, ]

df2$Days_Since <- unlist(Map(`-`, df$TIMESTAMP[inds], df$TIMESTAMP[inds-1]))
#    TIMESTAMP  ID Order_Type Days_Since_Last_Purchase
#    2017-06-16 55     Refund                       29
#    2017-06-28 36     Refund                       14
```

You can also choose for `mapply` instead of `Map` in most (all?) situations:

```
df2$Days_Since <- mapply(difftime, df$TIMESTAMP[inds], df$TIMESTAMP[inds-1])
```

**Note**: A benefit of this approach is that it only employs base R. However, as Moody_Mudskipper pointed out in the comments, this solutions only works when the data is chronologically ordered and every Refund-record is preceded by its corresponding Purchase-record. In most practical situations, this is a big deal!

Comment: It seems to work :)! you could make it simpler though, why not just do : `inds  <- which(df$Order_Type == "Refund");df2 <- df[inds, ];df2$Days_Since <- df$TIMESTAMP[inds] - df$TIMESTAMP[inds-1]` ? Also maybe mention that it will work only if the table is sorted by ID then TIMESTAMP

Comment: oh maybe the vectorized substraction works for me only because I have `lubridate` loaded

Comment: But there'll be issues if OP doesn't have the data from the start of all purchases, as some refunds would be attributed to a wrong purchase (instead of NA)

Comment: I like your suggestion in the first comment, much better of course! W.r.t. robustness, I think it is a welcome side-effect of packages like dplyr and tidyr that they account for such situations, but in this case, I don't think it adds much as it isn't part of the question here

Comment: But you're right, in base R the suggestion produces errors. I think because of the Date format?

Comment: I don't know exactly, it's always a pain to work with date vectors in base R, values tend to be coerced to integer in unexpected situations

Comment: Thanks for all the great input, as for the  Note: "Refund-record is preceded by its corresponding Purchase-record" from Ken S, Couldn't you apply a  
`sort()` in base r or `arrange()` from dpylr to sort by ID then TIMESTAMP prior to the calculation.

Comment: Yes, you could. It would just cost a couple of additional lines

Answer (score 2):

A solution uses `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  mutate(RowID = 1:n()) %>%
  mutate(TIMESTAMP = as.Date(TIMESTAMP)) %>%
  spread(Order_Type, TIMESTAMP) %>%
  fill(Refund, .direction = "up") %>%
  mutate(Days_Since_Last_Purchase = Refund - Purchase) %>%
  filter(Days_Since_Last_Purchase > 0) %>%
  arrange(ID, Refund, Days_Since_Last_Purchase) %>%
  group_by(ID, Refund) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  select(TIMESTAMP = Refund, ID, Days_Since_Last_Purchase)
dt2
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   ID, TIMESTAMP [2]
   TIMESTAMP    ID Days_Since_Last_Purchase
      <date> <int>                   <time>
1 2017-06-28    36                  14 days
2 2017-06-16    55                  29 days
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "TIMESTAMP   ID  Order_Type
2017-05-04  55  Purchase
                 2017-05-12  55  Purchase
                 2017-05-18  55  Purchase
                 2017-06-16  55  Refund 
                 2017-05-06  36  Purchase
                 2017-05-14  36  Purchase
                 2017-05-22  36  Purchase
                 2017-06-14  36  Purchase
                 2017-06-28  36  Refund 
                 2017-07-10  36  Purchase",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Won't it fail if you have several cycles of purchase/refund per id ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Thanks for you comments. I have updated my code. Now it can deal with multiple purchase cases.

Answer (score 2):

another `dplyr` / `tidyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(TIMESTAMP = as_date(TIMESTAMP)) %>%
  arrange(ID,TIMESTAMP) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(refund_group = lag(cumsum(Order_Type == "Refund"),1,0)) %>% # as table is sorted, and we're inside a given group, every instance of "Refund" marks the end of a refund_group
  group_by(ID,refund_group,Order_Type) %>%
  do({tail(.,1)}) %>% # we keep the last instance of Purchase & Refund for each refund_group
  ungroup %>%
  spread(Order_Type,TIMESTAMP) %>%
  mutate(Days_Since_Last_Purchase = Refund - Purchase)   %>% # that's basically the final table, but we strip it further to get exactly the expected output
  select(TIMESTAMP = Refund,ID,Days_Since_Last_Purchase) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Days_Since_Last_Purchase))
```

**results**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
   TIMESTAMP    ID Days_Since_Last_Purchase
      <date> <int>                   <time>
1 2017-06-28    36                  14 days
2 2017-06-16    55                  29 days
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `for` loop to show date differences in the same `table` in new `column`:

```
for(i in 2:nrow(df1)){
  df1$Days_Since_Last_Purchase[1] <- ""
  if((df1$Order_Type[i] == "Refund" & df1$Order_Type[i-1] == "Purchase") & (df1$ID[i] == df1$ID[i-1])){
      df1$Days_Since_Last_Purchase[i] <- difftime(df1$Timestamp[i],df1$Timestamp[i-1], units = c("days"))
  } else{
    df1$Days_Since_Last_Purchase[i] <- ""
  }
}

> df1
    Timestamp ID Order_Type Days_Since_Last_Purchase
1  2017-05-04 55   Purchase                         
2  2017-05-12 55   Purchase                         
3  2017-05-18 55   Purchase                         
4  2017-06-16 55     Refund                       29
5  2017-05-06 36   Purchase                         
6  2017-05-14 36   Purchase                         
7  2017-05-22 36   Purchase                         
8  2017-06-14 36   Purchase                         
9  2017-06-28 36     Refund                       14
10 2017-07-10 36   Purchase
```